# delete tail doesn't return the correct list

Tags: c, list, pointers, singly-linked-list

I'm having some issues with the delete tail function, It does not work when I'm freeing the current node, but when I work with the next node everything works fine. Can someone explain to me what is happening and why it does not work?

this is the list

```
    typedef struct node {
    int codice;
    struct node *next;
} nodo;

typedef nodo * lista;
```

the delete tail function which does not work is

```
lista rimuovi_in_coda(lista l){
    if(l == NULL) return NULL;
    lista l_scorri = l;
    while(l_scorri->next != NULL)
        l_scorri = l_scorri->next;

    free(l_scorri);
    l_scorri = NULL;
    return l;
}
```

in this one the list l is not modified:

```
input: 0, 4
output: 0, 4
```

the working one is:

```
lista rimuovi_in_coda(lista l){
    if(l == NULL || l->next == NULL) {
        free(l);
        return NULL;
    }
    lista l_scorri = l;
    while(l_scorri->next->next != NULL)
        l_scorri = l_scorri->next;

    free(l_scorri->next);
    l_scorri->next = NULL;
    return l;
}
```

in this one the list returned is as expected

```
input: 0, 4
output: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first function you are changing the local variable `l_scorri`

```
free(l_scorri);
l_scorri = NULL;
```

This does not change the value of the data member `next` of the preceding node.

In the second program you are indeed changing the data member next of the preceding node.

```
l_scorri->next = NULL;
```

The function can be written simpler. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node 
{
    int codice;
    struct node *next;
} nodo;

typedef nodo * lista;

int rimuovi_in_coda( lista *l )
{
    int success = *l != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        while ( ( *l )->next != NULL ) l = &( *l )->next;

        free( *l );
        *l = NULL;
    }

    return success;
}

int main( void )
{
}
```

Comment: therefore l_scorri = NULL I'm just changing where l_scorri will point but in l_scorri->next = NULL I'm changing the value where l_scorri->next IS pointing?

Comment: @MarcoA7 l_scorri = NULL changes the value of the variable l_scorri itself.

Answer (score 2):

You never reset any pointers or set any node's "next" to NULL. You just `free` an element but leave it in the list.

Comment: but what's the difference between freeing the current node rather than the node's next

Comment: The difference is not the freeing but setting the pointer to `NULL`. In your first version you only assign `NULL` to a local copy of the pointer. There is no relation to the list.

Comment: what relation has l_scorri->next with l
if l_scorri has no relation to l?